# Concatenating lines to a string in python

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I have a fasta file as follows:

```
>scaf1
AAAAAATGTGTGTGTGTGTGYAA
AAAAACACGTGTGTGTG
>scaf2
ACGTGTGTGTGATGTGGY
AAAAAATGTGNNNNNNNNYACGTGTGTGTGTGTGTACACWSK
>scaf3
AAAGTGTGTTGTGAAACACACYAAW
```

I want to read it into a dictionary in a away that multiple lines belonging to one sequence go to one key, the output would be:

```
{'scaf1': 'AAAAAATGTGTGTGTGTGTGYAAAAAAACACGTGTGTGTG', 'scaf2': 'ACGTGTGTGTGATGTGGYAAAAAATGTGNNNNNNNNYACGTGTGTGTGTGTGTACACWSK', 'scaf3': 'AAAGTGTGTTGTGAAACACACYAAW'}
```

The script I have written is:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

fastaseq = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

def readfasta(fastaseq):
    fasta_dict = {}
    for line in fastaseq:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            header = line.strip('\n')[1:]
            sequence = ''
        else:
            sequence = sequence + line.strip('\n')
        fasta_dict[header] = sequence 
    return fasta_dict

fastadict = readfasta(fastaseq)
print fastadict
```

It works correctly and fast for such a file but when the file size increases (that is about 1.5 Gb), then it becomes too slow. The step that is taking time is the concatenation part of the `sequence`. I was wondering if there is any faster way of concatenating the lines to a single string?

Comment: Maybe `sequence += line.strip(...)` will be faster, because here you're not extracting the value of `sequence`, adding data to it and then assigning to `sequence` again. Just `+=` and that's all.

Comment: Just changed it in my script, it indeed increased the speed, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenating strings with `+` requires to create a new string since Python strings are immutable, which is time consumer.

Use [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate them after all strings are ready,

```
import sys

def read_fasta(filename):
    fasta_dict = {}
    l = list()
    header = None
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'): # a new record
                # save the previous record to the dict
                if header:
                    fasta_dict[header] = ''.join(l) 
                    del l[:]    # empty the list

                header = line.strip().split('>')[1]
            else:
                l.append(line.strip())

        # save the last record
        fasta_dict[header] = ''.join(l) 

    return fasta_dict

fastadict = read_fasta(sys.argv[1])
print(fastadict)
```

Comment: Yep, Using a list and `join`ing at the end seems like a good idea here. I expect that appending items to a list is typically faster than concatenating them to a string (something like O(1) vs O(N)). For a header with a substantial number of following lines (say, 100), I'd expect a measurable performance boost.